# Should I avoid implicit behavior by passing a redundant parameter?

Tags: c++, api

I'm developing a class that, among other things, will create a block of memory and perform some processing on this memory. The user will do something like this:

```
MyClass m;
float* data = m.createData();
/* user writes to `data` ... */
m.processData();
```

Keep in mind that `createData()` will be called only once, `MyClass` keeps an internal pointer to `data`, and all `processData()` calls will always act on this data.

My question is about the signature of the `processData()` method. I'm a bit uncomfortable with the fact that `processData()` implicitly modifies `data`. Should I require `data` to be passed as a parameter (even being redundant) just to make this behavior explicit to the user?

```
MyClass m;
float* data = m.createData();
/* user writes to `data` ... */
m.processData(data);
```

Comment: Why you need to return data in `createData()` instead of manage it internally by the class?

Comment: @Calvin Because the user needs to access this data (write and read).

Comment: @Monfico, do you really need to return a `float*` to provide access to the data? Instead of doing that, you could provide methods `void setData(int index, float value)` and  `float getData(int index) const`

Comment: even `float* get() const` (or lock_buffer) sound better than returning pointer in createData(). `get()` gives better idea to the programmer `MyClass` owns the data.

Comment: @ArtonDorneles I didn't do that because the `m` object actually does much more than managing `data`, it is intended to be used only on the `main()` function. The `data` pointer could be passed around and used in other places by the user.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm a bit uncomfortable with the fact that processData() implicitly modifies data.

Actually, `processData` doesn't modify `data` at all. Given your description, it modifies the object that `data` points to. But only because the internal pointer happens to point to the same object.

> Should I require data to be passed as a parameter (even being redundant) just to make this behavior explicit to the user?

If you intend to use the internal pointer anyway, then definitely not. Requiring user to pass an argument that's not used would be very confusing.

If you intend to use the passed pointer instead, then it would not make much sense to store the pointer within the class.

> user needs to access this data (write and read).

The object oriented approach is to not return the pointer to the data, but instead write member functions to `MyClass` that perform the writing and reading.

A non-object-oriented approach is fine as well: Replace `createData` and `processData` with free functions, return a `std::unque_ptr<float[]>` (or better yet, use `std::vector`) to the data, and get rid of `MyClass` entirely.

Comment: > The object oriented approach is to not return the pointer to the data...

The problem with this is that the real class I'm developing does much more then just manage the memory pointed by the `data` pointer. It is actually a class that encapsulated the client side of a client-server application, and the memory block is going to be shared between client and server (yes, the client and server run on the same machine).
I think that including reading/writing methods to this class makes it too fat, so, on returning the pointer, I was hoping to transfer this burden somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not.

Your function `createData()` returns a pointer. This implies, that the data to which the pointer points might be modified.
If you want to pass a copy of your data to the user, don't pass a pointer (but it sounds like you don`t want that).

`processData()` is a member function of your `MyClass` - as long as it is not marked `const` you don't give any guarantees that you don't modify the internal data.

The only point where i would watch out is, if you want to invalidate the pointer you passed to the user. Then you should explicitly tell about this in your documentation or even switch to some kind of smart pointer.

If this approach seems to unsafe for you, it might be a better way to not return a pointer, but instead provide member functions to do the read/write access. This gives you full control about how and when the user changes your data, e.g. for thread-safety.